# Elasticsearch : What is the effect disabling replication and balancing

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have an ES cluster and an application indexing data into ES.

**EDIT**: The application creates indices in a dynamic way based on some business rules.

For example, if the application listen to tweets from Twitter API based on some hashtags it creates an index in ES for each hashtag. 
This way, each time a new hashtag comes, a new index is created in ES.

Sometimes, shard reallocation happen and at this stage, the cluster behaves poorly as the amount of data moved between nodes is huge.

From ES cluster API, we can disable shard reallocation and balancing.

What will be the effects (positive and negative) of disabling the reallocation and balancing?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a quite unorthodox way of organizing documents in Elasticsearch, wouldn't it be simpler to have a string `not_analyzed` field which would be an array of hashtabs (as a single tweet can have zero, one two or more hashtags).

If there was only one hashtag / tweet you could use it for [routing](https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing) them to a specific shard, if search performance is a concern for you.

Anyway, if you disable shard balancing then some machines would have increasingly disproportionate amount of documents on some machines and too few on others, this could hamper indexing and searching performance.

Also if you don't have any replicas of shards then in the event of a node shutdown part of you data would become inaccessible. I'm sure in the long run there are other downsides as well.

Comment: thnx for answer, I edited the question as the hashtags part was just an example. Regardless of the example, if the application receive about 3 million tweet per day, and we want to keep data of last three months (which means 3million doc * 30 * 3), we can put all this amount of data in one index and make the queries with a filter on the hashtag or create a separate index per hashtag. We chose the second approach. What do you think about this?

Comment: If you want to keep "x number of days of data" in ES it is a common pattern to have for example 1 index / day with sufficient number of shards for anticipated total number of documents, this can then easily be tuned in future. Also deleting old data is simple as you can delete whole indexes. Additionally you can use aliases to make queries on "all data", "last 7 days" etc. in a trivial manner. For common hashtags you could create filtered aliases. I'm not sure what would be the benefit from having a separate index per hashtag.